get hitbox as well as image to rotate around a point
I used Phaser.Actions.RotateAroundDistance(spinningfire.getChildren(), { x: 600, y: -1780 }, 0.02, 200) in order to make a the group spinning fire to spin around a sprite. the only problem is that the hitbox does not move with the fire image.
I am VERY new to phaser so I really do not have any idea on how to change hitboxes and other complicated stuff like this.
also here is all the relevant code
`function preload() 
{
//loading the fire image
this.load.image('fire', 'assets/fire.png')
}
function create()
{
    //creating spinning fire group
    spinningfire = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    spinningfire.create(600, -1600, 'fire')
}
function update()
{
     
Phaser.Actions.RotateAroundDistance(spinningfire.getChildren(){ 
x: 600, y: -1780 }, 0.02, 180)
}`


you will have to share the relevant Code or a short working demo, like in my  last answer  Since Phaser.Actions.RotateAroundDistance(...) works in my demo.

I have added all relavant code to the question. Also, it is not "off screen" because this is a game where the camera follows the players y position plus 200 and the objective of the game is to go up.

Also, thank you for helping me last time! The game would not be the same without you!

i tried making the spinning fire group not static and adding this; spinningfire.setImmovable(true);
spinningfire.setAllowGravity(false); but it did not work

I feel like if there was a way to make it a group with physics and properly cancel out gravity on it then it would be possible to make the hitbox also spin as well

I easily fixed it with a few tweaks to the group. the problem was that the static groups hitbox wanted to stay where it was because it has no physics. the answer was to create a group with no gravity but has physics. in order to do this I replaced the spinningfire = this.physics.add.staticGroup with spinningfire = this.physics.add.group({immovable: true, allowGravity: false}); this creates a group with physics but no gravity getting in the way of things.
